# How to html function store in database

Tags: database

> // -------------------------------------------------------
> // Called when the spin animation has finished by the callback feature of the wheel because I specified callback in the
> parameters.
> // -------------------------------------------------------
> function alertPrize()
> {
> // Get the segment indicated by the pointer on the wheel background which is at 0 degrees.
> var winningSegment = theWheel.getIndicatedSegment();
>
> ```
>             // Just alert to the user what happened.
>             // In a real project probably want to do something more interesting than this with the result.
>             if (winningSegment.text == 'LOOSE TURN')
>             {
>               var audio = new Audio('clickUp.mp3');
>               audio.play();
>                 alert('Sorry but you loose a turn.');
>             }
>             else if (winningSegment.text == 'BANKRUPT')
>             {
>               var audio = new Audio('clickUp.mp3');
>               audio.play();
>                 alert('Oh no, you have gone BANKRUPT!'); ***<----- Data out put want to database***
>             }
>             else
>             {
>               var audio = new Audio('click.mp3');
>               audio.play();
>                 alert("You have won " + winningSegment.text); ***<----- Data out put want to database***
>             }
>         }
> ```

Data output I want to store it to database
Thank you advance.

Comment: What data do you want to save? And what database are you using?

Comment: Database MySql and data is just number
Thank you advance.

Comment: sorry my english.